# How the some() method works in JavaScript in this array match-check code?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please consider this code:

```
let sites = ['cnn.com', 'nbc.com'];
if (sites.some(site => location.hostname.includes(site))) {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

I understand that the `some()` method checks if an array contains something but I didn't understand the specific usage here:

```
(site => location.hostname.includes(site))
```

This arrow doesn't seem to me like an arrow function because there's no `{}` after it. Also, it seems to me there is a "duplication" of the word *site*.

How is this statement is built and processed, and especially what is the arrow and the seeming duplication?

Comment: `{}` in an arrow function is optional, if the function body consists of just one expression. Read the docs about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: `Also, it seems to me there is a "duplication" of the word site.`, it's the name given to the callback, the first one is the name you want to use, the second one is you using it.  If they were both renamed to `arrayitem` it might make more sense for you what happening.

Comment: Name of the callback? I would call it parameter and argument. If there was more than one parameter, the term "callback" (as the sole function being called back in each execution) was still valid?

Comment: You can name it what you want, but the example of `site` I would say is the better option, but that's just my personal preference.  Also if performance is important, I would do it like -> `const sites = new Set(['cnn.com', 'nbc.com']);if (sites.has(location.hostname)) { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression:

```
site => location.hostname.includes(site)
```

Rely on the implicit return of arrow function, it's equivalent to:

```
site => { 
    return location.hostname.includes(site)
}
```

Also be carefull when returning object implicitly, instead of:

```
() => { prop1: "value", prop2: "value2"}
```

It should be:

```
() => ({ prop1: "value", prop2: "value2"})
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
site => location.hostname.include(site)
```

is same as

```
function(site) {
    return location.hostname.include(site)
}
```

That function is called for every item in arrays. In this case `cnn.com` and `cnbc.com`

The `some()` function check wether one of the function returns true. If one of this functions return true,

ex: `location.hostname.include('cnn.com')` return true

`some()` function will return true